# Browser freezing for a couple of second

Tags: javascript

When the following codes are running, it makes the browser freeze for a couple of secondes.
How could i prevent that ? Thanks

```
function rsfp_changePage(formId, page, totalPages, validate)
{
if (validate)
{
    var form = rsfp_getForm(formId);
    if (!ajaxValidation(form, page))
        return false;
}

for (var i=0; i<=totalPages; i++)
{
    var thePage = document.getElementById('rsform_' + formId + '_page_' + i);
    if (thePage)
        document.getElementById('rsform_' + formId + '_page_' + i).style.display = 'none';
}

var thePage = document.getElementById('rsform_' + formId + '_page_' + page);
if (thePage)
{
    thePage.style.display = '';
    try {
        eval('if (typeof rsfp_showProgress_' + formId + ' == "function") rsfp_showProgress_' + formId + '(' + page + ')');
    }
    catch (err) { }
}
}
```

...

You will find the form on http://www.ocsl.ch/dev
username : stackoverflow / 
password : stackoverflow
Login first and then go to http://www.ocsl.ch/dev/sejour-linguistique/adultes/demande-d-offre-en-ligne
Once on this page, click on the green button "suivant" and you will see that it freezes for a very little will.
Below the content form the script.js file which contain the ajaxvalidation fonction. 
Hope that helps a bit. Please ask if you need any thing else that may help.

```
function refreshCaptcha(componentId, captchaPath)
{
if(!captchaPath) captchaPath = 'index.php?option=com_rsform&task=captcha&componentId=' + componentId;
document.getElementById('captcha' + componentId).src = captchaPath + '&' + Math.random();
document.getElementById('captchaTxt' + componentId).value='';
document.getElementById('captchaTxt' + componentId).focus();
}

function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep)
{
var n = number, prec = decimals;
n = !isFinite(+n) ? 0 : +n;
prec = !isFinite(+prec) ? 0 : Math.abs(prec);
var sep = (typeof thousands_sep == "undefined") ? ',' : thousands_sep;
var dec = (typeof dec_point == "undefined") ? '.' : dec_point;

var s = (prec > 0) ? n.toFixed(prec) : Math.round(n).toFixed(prec); //fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;

var abs = Math.abs(n).toFixed(prec);
var _, i;

if (abs >= 1000) {
    _ = abs.split(/\D/);
    i = _[0].length % 3 || 3;

    _[0] = s.slice(0,i + (n < 0)) +
          _[0].slice(i).replace(/(\d{3})/g, sep+'$1');

    s = _.join(dec);
} else {
    s = s.replace('.', dec);
}

return s;
}

function buildXmlHttp()
{
var xmlHttp;
try
{
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (e)
{
    try
    {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return xmlHttp;
}

function ajaxValidation(form, page)
{
try
{
    var el = form.elements.length;
}
catch (err)
{
    form = this;
}

var xmlHttp = buildXmlHttp();
var url = 'index.php?option=com_rsform&task=ajaxValidate';

if (page)
    url += '&page=' + page;

var params = new Array();
var submits = new Array();
var success = false;
var formId = 0;
for (i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++)
{
    // don't send an empty value
    if (!form.elements[i].name) continue;
    if (form.elements[i].name.length == 0) continue;
    // check if the checkbox is checked
    if (form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && form.elements[i].checked == false) continue;
    // check if the radio is selected
    if (form.elements[i].type == 'radio' && form.elements[i].checked == false) continue;

    if (form.elements[i].type == 'submit')
    {
        submits.push(form.elements[i]);
        form.elements[i].disabled = true;
    }

    // check if form is a dropdown with multiple selections
    if (form.elements[i].type == 'select-multiple')
    {
        for (var j=0; j<form.elements[i].options.length; j++)
            if (form.elements[i].options[j].selected)
                params.push(form.elements[i].name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].options[j].value));

        continue;
    }

    if (form.elements[i].name == 'form[formId]')
        formId = form.elements[i].value;

    params.push(form.elements[i].name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(form.elements[i].value));
}

params = params.join('&');

xmlHttp.open("POST", url, false);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlHttp.send(params);
var success = true;

if (xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("\n") != -1)
{
    var response = xmlHttp.responseText.split("\n");
    // All spans set to no error
    var ids = response[0].split(',');
    for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(ids[i])) && document.getElementById('component'+ids[i]))
            document.getElementById('component'+ids[i]).className = 'formNoError';

    // Show errors
    var ids = response[1].split(',');
    for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(ids[i])) && document.getElementById('component'+ids[i]))
        {
            document.getElementById('component'+ids[i]).className = 'formError';
            success = false;
        }

    if (response.length == 4)
    {
        page = parseInt(response[2]) - 1;
        totalPages = parseInt(response[3]);
        rsfp_changePage(formId, page, totalPages, false);
    }

    for (var i=0; i<submits.length; i++)
        submits[i].disabled = false;
}

if (success == false && document.getElementById('rsform_error_' + formId))
{
    try {
        document.getElementById('rsform_error_' + formId).style.display = '';
    }
    catch (err) { }
}

return success;
}

function rsfp_addEvent(obj, evType, fn){ 
 if (obj.addEventListener){ 
   obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false); 
   return true; 
 } else if (obj.attachEvent){ 
   var r = obj.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn); 
   return r; 
 } else { 
   return false; 
 } 
}

function rsfp_getForm(formId)
{
var formIds = document.getElementsByName('form[formId]');
for (var i=0; i<formIds.length; i++)
{
    if (parseInt(formIds[i].value) != parseInt(formId))
        continue;

    var form = formIds[i].parentNode;       
    if (form.tagName == 'FORM' || form.nodeName == 'FORM')
        return form;

    while (form.parentNode)
    {
        form = form.parentNode;
        if (form.tagName == 'FORM' || form.nodeName == 'FORM')
            return form;
    }
}
}
```

---

Thanks @JuanMendes, it didn't help unfortunately. I made some reaserch to find out how could I modify the codes to send an asynchronous request but I didn't succeed. In the ajaxValidation fonction, there is

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, false);
```

if I change it to

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
```

it should then be an asynchronous request, isn't it.

When I tested it, it didn't freeze the browser, however it doesn't show the error if fields are not filled up on the form. Instead, it validates which is not mean to be. Any help ?

Comment: Can't tell, but ajaxValidation is probably not being used with async true

Comment: There's a lot of stuff missing from this question. For example, what does `ajaxValidation` do? Try to delete as much code as you can while still making the browser freeze and post it again.

Comment: Impossible to tell from this code - when is all this stuff being called? This is  just a function declaration. And what does ajaxValidation do?

Comment: I suspect that, somewhere outside the above code sample, you're performing a synchronous AJAX request in order get `ajaxValidation` to return a value. To prevent that, you'll need to make `ajaxValidation` asynchronous and use a callback function instead.

Answer (score 0):

As IAbstractDownvoteFactory mentioned, you're probably calling ajax in synchronous mode, which means exactly that, freeze the screen while you're waiting for the network call.

The reason it looks that way is that your `ajaxValidation` is returning a value. Typically, you would send an asynchronous request and your `ajaxValidation` would take a callback. Then the UI won't hang waiting for the XHR.

```
// This is an improvement over what you had
// Still poor code, since it's hard to tell what the function is doing
function rsfp_changePage(formId, page, totalPages, validate)
{
  var form = rsfp_getForm(formId);
  if (validate) {
    // Change your AJAX validation function to take a callback, which passes the return
    // value (asynchronous) instead of relying on a return value (synchronous)
    ajaxValidation(form, page, function(validationResult){
      if (validationResult) {
        showProgress();
      }
    });        
  } else {
    showProgress();
  }

  function showProgress() {
    for (var i=0; i<=totalPages; i++) {
      var thePage = document.getElementById('rsform_' + formId + '_page_' + i);
      if (thePage) {
        thePage .style.display = 'none';
      }

      var thePage = document.getElementById('rsform_' + formId + '_page_' + page);
      if (thePage) {
        thePage.style.display = '';
        // Don't use eval, use window and bracket to  avoid it
        var func = window["rsfp_showProgress_" + formId];
        if (typeof func  == "function") {
            func(page);
        }
      }
    }        
  }    
}
```

Comment: Hi @Juan, I posted the codes where the ajaxvalidation is. I made some research but I wasn't able to change the ajaxvalidation to take a call back. Could you perharps help with that ? thanks ;-)

Comment: What did you try? Give it an attempt and I'll help you, I can't write it all for you. Also, please indent your code